# Suppress/Stop/Get rid of Source Not Found tab in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm debugging an azure function written in core 2.0 (not sure if either of those datapoints are relevant but just in case).

When an error occurs at a line of "my"[1] source code, a new tab pops open with Source Not Found and then some diagnostic information not very clear to me you can see here [2].  Also, the pause button is no longer blue but grey. If I click on green continue button, the [grey] pause button goes blue again. But execution has left my function, no later break points have been hit, clearly the exception has been throw "into" the host / emulator / whatever.

In a console app, when debugging and when an exception occurs, the execution pointer stops on the line of the exception and a dialog pops up explaining the exception.  I can then drag the execution pointer back up (and in good ol .net framework, even edit and continue!).

What can I do to get the behaviour I'm currently experiencing to be a bit more like when I debug a .net framework console app?

I get the feeling that I've provided only a very amateurish explanation of what 's happening, do feel free to comment I can rewrite if necessary.

Cheers!

[1]
where my = "I've written some code that is calling a 3rd party library or nuget &C"

[2]
Locating source for 'C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\TaskMethodInvoker.cs'. Checksum: SHA1 {51 1b 74 b0 57 61 b6 58 ff a6 c7 c5 c7 d1 e8 9 34 36 72 b0}
The file 'C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\TaskMethodInvoker.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\TaskMethodInvoker.cs'...
Looking in the Edit-and-Continue directory 'Z:\Git\ReturnAdB2cGroups\enc_temp_folder\'...
The file with the matching checksum was not found in the Edit-and-Continue directory.
Looking in the projects for 'C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\TaskMethodInvoker.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Searching for documents embedded in the symbol file.
An embedded document was not found.
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\TaskMethodInvoker.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\TaskMethodInvoker.cs'.

Comment: note: I have "just my code" enabled.